# Tensor value assignment error - dimensionality problem

Tags: tensorflow

I am writing a Python code, visualizing an output of a ConvNet layer. Everything seems t be fine, but I get a dimension conversion error as below, at sess.run function call.

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128, 128, 3) for Tensor 'image-in:0', which has shape '(?, 128, 128, 3)'

```py
loaded_graph = tf.Graph()

image_to_use = train_images[0]
print(image_to_use.shape) # (128, 128, 3)

with tf.Session(graph=loaded_graph) as sess:

    # Load model
    loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(save_model_path + ".meta")
    loader.restore(sess, save_model_path)

    # Get Tensors from loaded model
    hidden_layer_1 = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name("hidden-layer-1:0")
    keep_prob_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep-prob-in")
    image_in_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, image_to_use.shape[0], image_to_use.shape[1], image_to_use.shape[2]], name="image-in")

    units = sess.run(hidden_layer_1, feed_dict={image_in_tf:image_to_use, keep_prob_tf:1.0})
```

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128, 128, 3) for Tensor 'image-in:0', which has shape '(?, 128, 128, 3)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in this line

`image_to_use = train_images[0]`

where `image_to_use` has dimension `(128, 128, 3)`.

Change it to this:

`image_to_use = np.asarray([train_images[0]])`

Now `image_to_use` has shape `(1, 128, 128, 3)` and it will be compatible with the expected shape `(?, 128, 128, 3)`.

Also, define the shape of your `image_in_tf` placeholder like this:

`image_in_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, ) + image_to_use[0].shape)`

Otherwise it will accept wrong dimensions in current format of your code (we changed the first dimensions).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Consider pressing on ‘accept this answer’ button